# Adding Spring Security @Secured annotation with the Spring Web Service disables Web Service endpoint

Tags: authentication, soap, spring-security, authorization, spring-ws

**Problem: When I add @Secured annotation at a web service method, the endpoint is disabled means I get *No endpoint mapping found* error when invoking the ws endpoint.**

Background: My Spring Web Service is secured to authenticate consumers using UsernameToken and Timestamp which works absolutely fine until I add @Secured to enforce role based authorization. The interceptors are configured in the spring-ws-servlet.xml using <sws:interceptors>.
Framework versions:

- spring ws: 2.0.5.RELEASE
- spring ws security: 2.0.5.RELEASE
- spring security: 3.0.7.RELEASE
- wss4j: 1.5.12

Here's the  sample of what I'm trying to do.

### Endpoint:

```
...

    @Endpoint
    public class XYZEndpoint implements XYZService{
        @Override
        @PayloadRoot(localPart = XYZ_REQUEST, namespace = NAMESPACE_XYZ)
        //@Secured({"ROLE_XYZ"})
        public XYZResponse produceXYZ(XYZRequest request) {
                    ...
            return new XYZResponse();
        }
    }

...
```

I am using global-method-security below to enable @Secured annotation as described by spring docs.

### spring-ws-servlet.xml

```
...

    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

....
```

Comment: Did you try using soapaction instead of the payload ?

Comment: This is classic Spring issue with *autodetected handlers* and *aspect based features*, like `@Secured` or `@Transactional`.

Comment: I figured that. I used an abstract class instead of an interface to get @Secured working.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and able to fix it with

```
<security:global-method-security proxy-target-class="true" secured-annotations="enabled"/>
```